# Is there a construction for a variable length block cipher that uses a fixed length one?

Tags: block-cipher, format-preserving, blocksize

I'm looking for some way to take a fixed length block cipher (for example AES) and turn it into a variable length one with comparable security. The new length may be bigger or smaller than the underlying block cipher's.

I'm considering going about this with an unbalanced feistel network, but I'm asking if there's an already accepted way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is standard work on this. You should see [*"On the Construction of Variable-Input-Ciphers"* by Bellare-Rogaway (PDF)](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~mihir/papers/lpe.pdf). They give definitions and constructions.

Comment: Instead of "just" linking the paper, would you mind to also add a quick sketch / intuition of one of techniques presented in the paper? And you may also want to tell our poor mobile users that they're about to open / download a PDF and _maybe_ also write out the title of the paper instead of "just" the authors, so we can still find it in case it goes down :) (I've just applied the latter part of this comment on your answer)

Comment: That works to increase block size, but I also need a way to reduce block size.

Comment: After looking over it more, I can see it talks about reducing the block size as well. I'm just having trouble wrapping my head around it.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that nobody knows yet how to reduce the block size in an efficient and provably secure manner. Quoting from the paper, *"We also remark that that the [block size can be reduced] using methods which we will later discuss. However, these methods have not been proven secure with desirable security bounds."*