# Encryption of 7 byte of data, output must be 7 byte

Tags: encryption, block-cipher, format-preserving

I'm looking for a cryptographic algorithm that inputs and outputs are both 7 bytes. Is there any such algorithm?

Comment: I'd suggest checking out some of our earlier [tag:format-preserving] encryption questions, such as https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/504/can-you-create-a-strong-blockcipher-with-small-blocksize-given-a-strong-blockci, https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20035/what-is-the-most-computationally-efficient-way-of-generating-pseudo-random-permu and maybe https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/48808/is-there-a-construction-for-a-variable-length-block-cipher-that-uses-a-fixed-len.

Comment: CTR mode. ${}{}$

Comment: Are there any security constraints in terms of bits? (i.e. given that 7 times 8-bits per byte would be a total of 56-bits with that much potential maximum security)

Comment: @kelalaka: That only works if you have an (implicit) unique nonce to go with each piece of data to be encrypted (or if you only ever encrypt one piece of data per key).

Comment: Reduced-size Feistel network based on keyed XOF.